# Where are the users in my Ubuntu?

Tags: directory, users

I created 2 users in my Ubuntu and now I can't find them. Can someone tell me where are they placed? I want to configure their information and permissions for the sake of practice.

Comment: How did you create them? what exactly are you trying to "find" (their home directories? passwd file entries? user IDs?)

Comment: when i am typing /etc/passwd i get a messege "not a directory"

but from what i understood this is where the users are..

Comment: i want to know the details of each user i made

Answer (score 1):

From the Launcher click on System Settings -> under the **System** heading click *User Accounts*. A User Accounts window will open and you can select a user to view that user's account information, including Account Type, Language, Password (requires authentication), Automatic Login (ON/OFF), and Last Login.

To view the user(s) information from the terminal type:

```
grep /home /etc/passwd
```

This command will show several attributes for each user. The user attributes are:

```
username:password:UID:GID:info:home directory:shell
```

The `adduser` tool is the best way to add a new user using the command line. When you add a new user using the `adduser`, everything that is necessary for a new user to use the GUI is created. For more information about using `adduser` see: [What is the best way to add a new user using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375094/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-new-user-using-the-command-line/375110#375110).

Use `deluser` to remove a user or group from the system using the command line. The `deluser` command has options to remove all files on the system owned by the user and for backing up all files before deleting them.

Normally you would use `sudo` before both `adduser` and `deluser`.

Comment: Thank you very much karel!    

   i allso want to know i do i change them?

   assuming of course that im the user root